# Using object reference (this) in called function

Tags: javascript, html

I have rewritten this question as parts of the original were solved to a simpler solution:

I have a dynamically created table where there will potentially be over 100 table cells () that wont have ID's for them. When a table cell is clicked a onclick event fires and a conditional check is done to determine if it is the first click of a 2 click series or the second click. The conditional determines which value of 2 hidden form fields is set.

Now here is the simple part im trying to accomplish: onclick, IF it is the first click I want the background color of the  object that triggered the function to be color1 else if it is the second click then it will be color2.

The code:  [(JSFiddle Here)](http://jsfiddle.net/r3jaapj5/1/)

CSS

```
#test tr td {text-align:center; border: thin black solid;}
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>
var x = 0;
var click = 0;
function res(zz) {
if (click == 0) {document.getElementById('start').value=zz; click = 1;} else
{document.getElementById('end').value=zz; click = 0;}
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="start" id="start" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="end"  id="end" value="">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />    
</form>

 <div id="starget"></div>
    <div id="etarget"></div>

    <table width="100%" id="test">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Tech</th><th>0800</th><th>0900</th><th>1000</th><th>1100</th><th>1200</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
<td>Bill</td>
<td>XXX</td>
<td onclick="res(0900);"></td>
<td>XXX</td>
<td>XXX</td>
<td onclick="res(1200);"></td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

This change works IF i want the background color between the first click and second click to be the same:

```
<td onclick="res(0900);this.style.backgroundColor='green';"></td>
```

This below however does not work, since the calling object () passes no reference of itself (this.style....) to the function, however this is in fact the way i need it to work because i need the conditional check to determine what color to set the background to:

```
function res(zz) {
    if (click == 0) {document.getElementById('start').value=zz; click = 1;this.style.backgroundColor='green';} else {document.getElementById('end').value=zz; click = 0;this.style.backgroundColor='red';} }
```

Comment: So the table data is coming from PHP/server-side. I would have a function that runs on the page load, using ajax to call the php to return the table data, then i would use javascript to append the new data (Dynamic). You can set evenhandlers for each call that will trigger a function to set a timer start/stop. Within the stop timer you can again use ajax to submit the value of that cell for php to save the new data or insert new data.

Comment: @NewToJS I apologize, not start/stop time as like a stop watch timer... i meant the dispatchers for the technicians are going to assign a block of time that can vary for each new ticket they are assigning to the technician, like a day planner. So by example.... a new plumbing call for "Jim" might be assigned to start at 1600Hrs and end at 1800Hrs.

Comment: Can you give me an example of your table structure for the database please? Is the structure set the same as the the example table shown in this question?

Comment: @NewToJS I have restructured the question so the original direction is not really the same, thank you for the efforts you had made so far.

Comment: About the problem with the `this` context: Use `onclick="res.call(this, 0900);"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to pass 'this' to the function res

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/r3jaapj5/2/

HTML:

```
<td onclick="res(0900, this);"></td>
```

Corresponding JS tweak:

```
function res(zz, el) {
    if (click == 0) {document.getElementById('starget').innerHTML=zz; click = 1; el.style.backgroundColor='green';} else {document.getElementById('etarget').innerHTML=zz; click = 0;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know you could pass 'this' as a variable

Comment: yep, it is super-handy for exactly what you're doing here!